# Google Authentication with Service Account fails (node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-api, jwt

I'm trying out a (node.js) sample app to authenticate against Google API and then make a Google Drive request. The sample I am trying to run is from the github readme of the googleapis node.js library [using jwt](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#using-jwt-service-tokens):

```
var jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
  '123...xyz@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  './key.pem',
  null,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  'my.personal@gmail.com');

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
  drive.files.list({ auth: jwtClient }, function(err, resp) {
    // handle err and response
  });
});
```

Authentication fails with:

```
{ error: 'unauthorized_client',
  error_description: 'Unauthorized client or scope in request.' }
```

I'm not 100% sure about the 'my.personal@gmail.com'. Using my Client ID, I receive the error 'Invalid impersonation prn email address.'.

I have created service account client ID, service email and certificate fingerprints according to documentation. Do I have to specify additional things? Is my scope incorrect? If it is, what should it be?

Google Drive API is enabled in the Google Developer Console. I also activated the trial account.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ugh, after trying many things, the result is rather simple: doing the above sample without  'impersonate'-email it just worked. Code:

```
var jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
  '123...xyz@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  './key.pem',
  null,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);
```

The example from the readme is available as a complete file inside examples ([here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/jwt.js)).

Comment: i know this is old - but have you tried this https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation to allow 'impersonate'?

Comment: @DaveBriand: well, it's not that long ago. But I already start to forget. For my purpose the imporsonate is not required (frankly, I'm not quite sure when it is). My use case is a rather simple one (accessing public drive data).

Comment: OH MY GOSH thank you. I have been at this for hours... you genius you.

Comment: I should be allowed to upvote a 2nd time. This saved me once and apparently one of my stashes wasn't updated properly and it just saved me again. I was including an email address as one more parameter after the scopes and this made me realize that was the problem.

Comment: For the record, it looks like the problem library is here or the underlying libraries. I see where the subject is set, but unless there's something I'm missing on the other side to enable impersonation, something here isn't right. https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/lib/auth/jwtclient.js

Comment: I had this same problem accessing the Google Analytics API and realized that if you are not impersonating a specific user you must add the client_email to your analytics profile and give it Read/Analyze rights to the account.

Comment: Btw, your solution worked for go app engine project, too. Thanks!