# Accessing Google API from aws lambda : Invalid OAuth scope

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am still struggling with Google's terminology of apis and services but my goal is to have automated functions via aws lambda which act on a G Suite Account (domain?) or more specific on users of this domain.

For now I just want to list all users of that domain. I run this code locally for testing.

**What I have done:**

- I created a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- I downloaded the json key file which contains the private key, private key id and so on
- I enabled G Suite Domain-wide Delegation.
- I delegated domain-wide authority to the service account from the GSuite Account
- I added the following scopes for the client in the GSuite Admin Console:

  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group

  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

**This is the implementation:**

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
keyFile: "credentials.json",
scopes:
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
 });

const service = google.admin({ version: "directory_v1", auth });
service.users.list(
{
  domain: "my.domain.com",
  maxResults: 10,
  orderBy: "email",
},
(err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.error("The API returned an error:", err.message);

  const users = res.data.users;
  if (users.length) {
    console.log("Users:");
    users.forEach((user) => {
      console.log(`${user.primaryEmail} (${user.name.fullName})`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("No users found.");
  }
}
);
```

I am not sure why I have to add the scopes in the `GoogleAuth` object but I took this from the google documentation.

When I run this I get the following error:

`The API returned an error: invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.`

Comment: So right now you are running your code locally for testing, for your domain and you are the admin of this domain?

Comment: yes, that is correct. but the credentials are the one from the service account. And it definitely has all the scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Directory API can only be used by admins
- A Service account is not an admin
- If the service account shall act on behalf on the admin, you need to

  - enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation (as you already did)
  - impersonate the service account as the admin by setting the user to be impersonated

In general, when you are using a service account you need to build the authentication flow, as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests), that is you need to create JSON Web Token (JWT) specifying the user to impersonate.

A sample code snippet for Javascript:

```
        const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            privatekey.client_email,
            null,
            privatekey.private_key,
            scopes,
            user // User who will be impersonated (needs to be an admin)
        );

        await jwtClient.authorize();

        return jwtClient;
```

Comment: thank you! However I could not find any documentation about the authentification with the googleapi-nodejs rather the samples and this bit: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#authentication-and-authorization
Furthermore I do not understand why there is no credentials from the admin account needed when you impersonate the service account in code with it. Isn't there something missing?

Comment: The code above is for node.js, for more complete sample check [here](https://medium.com/@jason_dark/how-to-connect-to-the-g-suite-apis-using-a-service-account-key-with-node-js-659e97981a04) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995671/impersonate-user-with-google-calendar-api-oauth2-service-account-node-js).

Comment: thanks, it worked with the sample. However I could not find any "real" documentation on the authentication api. But I think I am beginning to understand. There is no super admin which I can impersonate with a service account which then can use any apis on every user like changing users email settings. So therefore I have to impersonate as the user itself I guess.

Comment: Does your domain not have an admin? Because the user himself will not have access to Admin SDK methods if he does not have an admin role.

Comment: well yes for this specific example you are right. And as you mentioned for using the directoryApi and admin user is needed. But lets say I want to change the email signature of all users. My idea was to have this service acount with the appropriate right which than can do that. But afaik you have to impersionate which each single user do change the signature for each user one by one.

Comment: Yes, for this you would need to impersonate each user!