# How to use a Google service account in the place of oAuth2Client to use Google Apps API?

Tags: node.js, google-api

I've successfully used the oAuth2Client with Node using [Google's Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

However, I want to avoid the consent screen and do a service to service authentication.

I've found [Node GToken](https://github.com/googleapis/node-gtoken) to get a token, but where do I place it in the code, and how do I use it?

```
const key = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXXX...';
const { GoogleToken } = require('gtoken');
const gtoken = new GoogleToken({
  email: 'my_service_account_email@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  scope: ['https://scope1', 'https://scope2'], // or space-delimited string of scopes
  key: key
});
```

I've also found the following code on how to implement [Service to Service Authentication](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-to-service-authentication), but it seems to be implemented for Google's compute service. The example states:

> For example, a JWT auth client will be created when your code is running on your local developer machine, and a Compute client will be created when the same code is running on a configured instance of Google Compute Engine.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const compute = google.compute('v1');

async function main () {
  // This method looks for the GCLOUD_PROJECT and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  // environment variables.
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute']
  });

  // obtain the current project Id
  const project = await google.auth.getProjectId();

  // Fetch the list of GCE zones within a project.
  const res = await compute.zones.list({ project, auth });
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

I've found code on other sites that uses `googleapis.auth.JWT`, but I can't find any documentation on that for service to service accounts used with Google Apps.

[Here it says that a service account isn't what's needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518378) Unfortunately, I don't understand what the question is to understand if the answer applies to my situation, too. What I want to do is to authorize my node.js app to use my drive without the need for me to allow it to access every time.

**I don't know how to translate the Quickstart code to accommodate a service account.**

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27956244/7108653

Comment: Which API are you trying to access, is it the Google Drive API? If yes, then what are you trying to do, upload files, edit a spreadsheet, something else?

Comment: @Tanaike If I did get the jwtClient, where would I insert it in the Quickstart code?

Comment: @AlexBaban I just want to create a simple file in a team drive without getting the consent prompt.

Comment: @yaharga Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted, just now. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to a "Google Drive for Business" account, so I'm posting what I could do with my personal Google Drive ("My Drive").

I also read on some pages on Internet that you can't share a "Team Drive", but maybe you could add the service account as a team member.

This code lists the files in a folder on "My Drive" after I shared the folder with a service account.

```js
// load library
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// configure a JWT auth client
const privatekey = require("./privatekey.json");

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
    ]
);

jwtClient.authorize()
    .then(function (tokens) {
        // console.log(tokens);
        console.log("Authentication successfull.\n");

        // list the files once authenticated
        listFiles(jwtClient);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw (error);
    });


function listFiles(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
    drive.files.list({
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        // q: "name contains 'foo'"
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

}
```

`privatekey.json` is the private key of the service account (downloaded and renamed) from "Google Cloud Platform", where of course "Google Drive API" is enabled.

Inside `privatekey.json` you can find the email address for the service account which you could then try to add it to the "Team Drive".

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to send emails from Gmail API with a Service Account. Gmail API has to be enabled in Google Cloud. This is useful to send emails from an specific gmail address you own to others, without any auth screen.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { config } = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');

config();

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'];

async function main() {
    const privatekey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS));
    console.log(privatekey.client_email)
    const auth = new google.auth.JWT({
        subject: 'THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_YOU_OWN',
        email: privatekey.client_email,
        key: privatekey.private_key,
        scopes: SCOPES

    });
    
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: auth });

    const destinatary = 'destinatary@destinatary.com'
    
    const message = `To: ${destinatary}\r\n` +
                    'Subject: Mail Subject \r\n' +
                    '\r\n' +
                    'Mail Content';


    const response = await gmail.users.messages.send({
        userId: 'me',
        requestBody: {
            raw: Buffer.from(message).toString('base64'),
        }
    });
    console.log('Mail Sent:', response.data);
  }

main()
```

The .env file has to look like this, just containing the path to your service account key.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./gmail_sa.json
```